# Why BufferedReader is faster than Scanner?

Tags: java, performance, bufferedreader

I know that using a **BufferedReader** is quicker than using a **Scanner** since the **Scanner** reads and parses the Stream while the **BufferedReader** only reads the Stream.

However, I do not understand why the **BufferedReader** would still be quicker if I'm parsing the Stream after reading it from the **BufferedReader**, wouldn't this be essentially the same thing the **Scanner** is doing ? Both of them are reading and parsing, so why is the **BufferedReader** still quicker ?

Let's say I'm taking integers as an input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
   System.out.println(x);

   }
```

Won't this be the same as this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int x = sc.nextInt();
   System.out.println(x);

   }
```

1. So is my understanding of how this works correct ?
2. Does the larger buffer size of the **BufferedReader** also help ?

Comment: From memory, `Scanner` makes heavy use of regular expression workflows, which adds to the performance hit of the API

Comment: I recommend that you check out Scanner and BufferedReader's respective source code in OpenJDK's repo. I think it'd be very insightful.

Comment: You can read the source code for `Scanner` and you will see that reading the `nextInt` is actually quite a complex workflow, which allows it to more adaptable

Comment: General rule. Classes that are designed to do a specific function will be more efficient than classes than classes that are designed to do many functions. A scanner also needs to be able to parse Strings and Doubles etc, so it will have additional logic not strictly related to parsing an int.

Comment: @camickr how would the additional logic make the function less efficient? Wouldn't there be a method for each particular case (nextInt(), next() ...) and so each method would be efficient for what it's meant to do ? In other words, I mean adding extra functions should not make them less efficient.

Comment: @MohamedShereef  *how would the additional logic make the function less efficient?* Because its "additional" logic. You don't get anything free. Any extra work will add overhead. If you type "123 456, 789", the Scanner will have to read and parse each int value every time you invoke the nextInt() method. There is extra parsing to find the delimiter for each int value. The extra parsing adds overhead. In the case of the BufferedReader when you invoke the parsInt(...) method you would get an invalid int value because it would attempt to parse the entire string as a single int.

Answer (score -4):

> ***BufferReader*** has large buffer of **8KB byte** Buffer as compared to Scanner. Scanner is bit slower as it need to parse data as well.
> BufferReader is faster than Scanner as it only reads a character
> stream

Difference bettween bufferReader VS scanner

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-scanner-and-bufferreader-class-in-java

Comment: That TutorialsPoint page is not a credible source for this.  It is speculation.  No benchmarks.  No citations.  (And some of what is says is patently incorrect; e.g. "synchronous" ... when it should say "synchronized".  Duh!)